# how to access selected item in the asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

1-) if I have lots of text, button, link ext in my page, in php when I use them as an array it is possible to use them with the same name. How can I do the same thing in asp.net?

2-) I have so many image buttons in my page, my question is: how can I get the selected immage button's id? because I pring them in the for loop I could not find any solution.

this is my code is below 
first "for loop" is for RSS second "for loop" is for stars and some divs

```
        string baslik = "";
        string icerik = "";
        string imageid = "";
   int j = 0;
 if (divflag == false)
  {


    for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
    {
        j++;

         baslik = "baslik" + i;
         icerik = "icerik" + i;
         imageid = "Img"+i;
        this.icerik.InnerHtml = list[i].Description;
        this.baslik.NavigateUrl = list[i].Link;
        this.baslik.Text = list[i].Title;


   %>

<div class="sag-re">-
            <div class="sag-re-baslik" runat="server"><asp:HyperLink ID=baslik         runat="server">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink></div>
                <!--<div class="sag-re-resim"><img src="images/rss-image.jpg" width="120" height="120"  /></div>-->
            <div class="sag-re-icerik" id = icerik runat="server">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc iaculis blandit mauris, in tincidunt erat scelerisque mollis, ac orci. </div>
            <div class="oy-verme">
                 <!-- <body onload="getDivs()"> -->

           <!--  <input type="image"
            src="images/yildiz.png" 
            ID="ImgButton"                                
                runat="server" OnServerClick="ImgButton_ServerClick" />-->
                <% for (j = i * 5 + 1; j < (i *5)+6; j++)
        {

            imageid = "Img" + j;

                       %>
                        <div class="yildiz"><asp:ImageButton ID=Imageid runat="server" Height="19px" 
                        ImageUrl="~/images/yildiz.png" onclick="ImageButton"+<%j %>+"_Click" Width="20px" 
                        style="position: relative; top: 13px; left:6px; float:left; "   /></div>


       <% } %>


        <div class="oy-sil"><img src="images/oy-sil.png" width="11" height="13" style="position: relative; top: 30px; " /></div>
            </div>
             <div class="bilgi" id="rate"><b>Rate</b> : 2.52  &nbsp;<img     src="images/mail.jpg" width="12" height="8" /><a href="#"> Mail</a> &nbsp; <img src="images/favorites.png" width="9" height="9" /><a href="#"> Add to favorites</a>&nbsp; <img src="images/tags.png" width="9" height="8" /><a href="#"> Add Tags</a> &nbsp; <img src="images/comment.png" width="11" height="8" /><a href="#"> Add Comment</a> &nbsp; <img src="images/show-comment.png" width="9" height="10" /> <a href="#">Show Comments</a><br /> <b>Tags</b> : tag1, tag2, tag3</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into using a repeater control instead of attempting to do a for loop within the ASP.NET page. ASP.NET typically works using the event-based model and databinding. So what you would do is to bind your repeater to your datasource add an event handler to the onItemDataBound event for your repeater and get the controls using the findControl method to set the properties for that specific control. Check out this link...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1847790/565792

Comment: Check out this link which shows the basics of the markup syntax. Your version is a little more complicated since you have controls within the repeater that you will need to bind to on ItemDataBound. You can get those subcontrols using the technique that I linked to  in my answer. http://www.learn-asp.net/asptutorials/Repeater.aspx