# How to obtain a textbox control from a div of repeater row?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, repeater

I'm trying making a shoppingcart and when I press the updatebutton for 1 of the products to update the amount of that product I need to get the textbox that belongs to it.

To manage this I bounded the productID to a div where the textbox is in so I can get the right textbox. My question is how do I get the value of this textbox?

here is the div

```
<td id="Td1" class="cart_update" runat="server" style="border-width: 0px 1px 1px 0px;">
    <div id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductID") %>' runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbx" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductAmount") %>' CssClass="carttextbox" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btn_update" runat="server" OnCommand="btn_update_Click" Text="Update" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductID") %>' />
        <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" OnCommand="btn_Click" Text="Remove" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductID") %>' />
    </div>
</td>
```

this is what I have in my code behind so far

```
protected void btn_update_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    int command = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    foreach(RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
    {
        TextBox tbx = find the right textbox;
        if(tbx != null)
        {
            foreach (ShoppingCart r in cart.shoppingcart)
            {
               if (r.ProductID == command)
               {
                   r.ProductAmount = Convert.ToInt32(tbx.Text);
               }
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Comment: You want to find the right textbox ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to FindControls in repeater control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736552/how-to-findcontrols-in-repeater-control)

Comment: yourRepeaterRow.FindControl("yourTextBoxID") is the way to manage that.

Comment: `TextBox tbx = (TextBox)Item.FindControl("tbx");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach(RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
{
    var tbx = item.FindControl("tbx") as TextBox;
    if(tbx != null)
    {
        foreach (ShoppingCart r in cart.shoppingcart)
        {
           if (r.ProductID == command)
           {
               r.ProductAmount = Convert.ToInt32(tbx.Text);
           }
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `.FindControl()` method. this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritem.findcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Or in more specific cases, I already found useful to simply loop (recursively) across `item.Controls`.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
foreach (RepeaterItem lvi in myRepeater.Items) {


TextBox tb = (TextBoxcb )lvi.FindControl("myTextBox");


}
```

Comment: that works only weird problem is that the productamount in the list doesn't seem to change. The price changes but when I go back into the shoppingcart the amount changes back to 1